# Configure two ipaddress from same subnet using 2 Bridged adaptor VirtualBox

Tags: networking, ethernet, gateway

I have configured 2 interface with 2 Bridged adaptors in Virtual Box from same subnet, the `/etc/network/interfaces` file configuration for two bridge network is shown below.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.169.100.10
network 192.169.100.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.169.100.255
gateway 192.169.100.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.169.100.20
network 192.169.100.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.169.100.255
```

However I can ping only the gateway configured ipaddress that is eth0 from another subnet, if I change the gateway to other interface only that machine is reachable. If I configure gateway to both the machines then I cannot access the network(I guess it creates network loop). How do I configure my machine such that both ipaddresses are accessible from other subnets. Tried to add metrics for 1 and 2 for eth0 and eth1 using ip command but still did not work. Any help is much appreciated. (Note once the machine is up I can see both these static ips configured, and The router at the end of subnet has dhcp enabled for this subnet)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `gateway 192.168.100.1` line from the interfaces file and add a static route instead:

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.100.1
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I cannot access the machine if I do not set default gateway